# Is the move constructor only come in handy if my class has a member that is a raw pointer?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I am currently studying the move constructor and the copy constructor. Based on my current understanding, these constructors are used to initialize an object of class X by providing another object of the same class type X. However, there is a distinction between the two: the copy constructor takes a non-temporary object as input, while the move constructor takes a temporary object.

Both the copy and move constructors are particularly useful when a class has a member that is a raw pointer, which may point to memory allocated on the heap.

so what if my class doesn`t have a pointer member just a collection of members of integers and strings and array of doubles for example , how would the copy and move constructor be so important and remove the overhead provided by the default argument constructors?
and how would the implementation of the two constructors be done in this case?
I am taking about the C++ language

I haven`t tried this case yet. but I tried it with the case of my class has a raw pointer

Comment: [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) might interest you.

Comment: It seems rule of 0 (possibly `= default;`) would do the job here.

Comment: Generally, move constructors are useful for classes that own some resources (which either cannot be copied or for which making copies is expensive). A class with a pointer member does not need to own the pointee, and a class without a pointer member may have some resource as well. So, the member pointer is not an indicator by itself.

Comment: Please, don't spam C++ version tags. This question does not seem to be related to tagged C++ standards; it is pretty generic.

Comment: The compiler will generate a move constructor for you by default. If you're asking when to write a *custom* one, then yes, mostly for pointer members, or various resource handles (files, sockets, etc). Same applies for all copy and move operations, and destructors. Most of your classes shouldn't have custom ones, because most of them shouldn't deal directly with manually allocated memory or resource handles.

Comment: As a typical example of a class that holds a resource but not a pointer: Think of an abstraction of a network connection. Usually a network connection is handled by a *descriptor*, which is a simple integer value.  It makes little sense to copy a network connection object, but it does make sense to move it when transferring ownership of the connection from one object to another.

Comment: It's not just important for avoiding copying duplicating memory pointed to by raw pointers, but also, if there's some other resource that cannot be duplicated in a reasonable way, but shouldn't prevent the containing type from being duplicated. Examples would be `std::thread`, `std::promise` and `std::unique_ptr`. Furthermore the type need not directly contain the raw pointer; members of type `std::vector` or `std::string`. Also there are non-allocation related cases where moving is cheaper: copying a `std::shared_ptr` has to modify an atomic counter possibly reducing optimization potential...

Comment: "Is the move constructor only come in handy if my class has a member that is a raw pointer?" - No.  It's useful in many more cases than that.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, move constructors and move assignment operators are only needed in two scenarios:

1. You want your non-POD class to be efficiently movable (e.g. std::vector, std::list, etc);
2. Your class cannot be copied for some reasons but it needs to be movable (e.g. std::unique_ptr, std::move_only_function, etc).

> Both the copy and move constructors are particularly useful when a class has a member that is a raw pointer, which may point to memory allocated on the heap

Not just a memory resource but generally any type of resource/data that doesn't rest in the object representation of a class instance but still belongs to it. It might be a socket, thread, file handle, or something else. An example is the `std::string` class which may own a buffer of characters that might be located somewhere else in the memory. In other words, the underlying buffer might not be inside a `std::string` object itself. But it owns the buffer by having a pointer member to it plus a few other members.

Take a look at below example:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo( const std::string& str, const double val )
    : str_ { str }, val_ { val }
    {}

    // copy ctor
    Foo( const Foo& rhs )
    : str_ { rhs.str_ }, val_ { rhs.val_ }
    {}

    // move ctor
    Foo( Foo&& rhs ) noexcept
    : str_ { std::move( rhs.str_ ) }, val_ { std::exchange( rhs.val_, 0.0 ) }
    {}

    void print_members()
    {
        std::cout << str_ << " " << val_ << "\n";
    }

private:
    std::string str_;
    double val_;
};

int main( )
{
    Foo f { "some text", 1.0 };
    Foo f1 { f };
    Foo f2 { std::move( f ) };

    f.print_members( );   // " 0" semantically empty after being *moved from*
    f1.print_members( );  // "some text 1"
    f2.print_members( );  // "some text 1"
}
```

As can be seen, the creation of `f2` through move construction will be more efficient than the creation of `f1` through copy construction. Because it simply moves the `f.str_` to `f2.str_` so it does not copy the underlying buffer of `f.str_` to that of `f2.str_`. In other words, it simply moves the ownership of that buffer of `char`s to `f2`. Also, note that the above class doesn't need its copy/move constructors explicitly defined since the compiler can create them implicitly and more efficiently. However, they were implemented for the purpose of demonstration.

> what if my class doesn`t have a pointer member just a collection of members of integers and strings and array of doubles

Yes, obviously implementing a move constructor/assignment operator for a POD class (more accurately [*standard layout*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType)) is not going to increase efficiency in most cases since those operations will be equivalent to copying that class. So for instance, if the above `Foo` class didn't have a `std::string` member it would be a standard layout type and would not necessarily need move semantics implemented.

**Note**: The following is not always true

> the copy constructor takes a non-temporary object as input, while the move constructor takes a temporary object

The copy constructor can take temporaries (*rvalues*) too. And the move constructor can take *lvalues* that were cast to *xvalue* via `std::move` as shown in `Foo f2 { std::move( f ) };` where `f` is a non-temporary.

Comment: For this example, you don't need custom copy/move constructors at all.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat True. Only for demonstration.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I added a note that briefly explains that piece.

Comment: A note about `std::forward` would improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The modern advice for constructors is known as the rule of zero/five.

0. Ideally, you should write none of the destructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment and move assignment operators.  You either `=default` then, `=delete` them, or leave the compiler to write them.

And then the rule of 5:

5. If you are managing resources, you have to write a destructor.  Once you write a destructor, you must write or delete the move constructor, move assignment, copy constructor and copy assignment.

This pair of rules isn't perfect, but covers 99.9% of classes and structs you will right.

The next bit is that you should manage resources in classes whose purpose it is to manage resources.  `std::vector` manages a contiguous buffer of memory, `std::unique_ptr` manages a uniquely owned object, `std::unique_lock` manages a lock around a mutex, etc.

That is all they do -- they manage that resource.  They have next to no business logic around the thing they are managing.

If your class uses such resource-management classes to manage resources, then it can use the rule of Zero!

Which then moves your Five special method classes to being a relatively small number of classes.  Only when you have a new category of resources do you need to write a new class that has manually written destructors, or copy/move construct/assignment.